# Deleting a node from my dynamic list

Tags: c

I created a dynamic list where each node contains a word, i created a function to delete a single node and free the memory that the node was using, my function, however, doesn't delete the node. When i type the world that it should delete, i only get "not found" as output, the error is in the delete function but i'm struggling to find it, could it be with the if statements that's supposed to loop through the nodes and find the one to remove?

```
    // Inserting and deleting nodes in a list
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// self-referential structure                       
struct listNode {                                      
   char *data; // each listNode contains a character 
   struct listNode *nextPtr; // pointer to next node
}; 
typedef struct listNode ListNode; // synonym for struct listNode
typedef ListNode *ListNodePtr; // synonym for ListNode*

// prototypes
void insert(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char *value);
char delete(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char value);
int isEmpty(ListNodePtr sPtr);
void printList(ListNodePtr currentPtr);
void instructions(void);
int main(void)
{ 
   ListNodePtr startPtr = NULL; // initially there are no nodes
   char item[20]; // char entered by user
   instructions(); // display the menu
   printf("%s", "? ");
   unsigned int choice; // user's choice
   scanf("%u", &choice);
   // loop while user does not choose 3
   while (choice != 3) { 
      switch (choice) { 
         case 1:
            printf("%s", "Enter a character: ");
            scanf("%s", item);
            insert(&startPtr, item); // insert item in list
            printList(startPtr);
            break;

     case 2: // delete an element
            // if list is not empty
            if (!isEmpty(startPtr)) { 
               printf("%s", "Enter character to be deleted: ");
               scanf("%s", &item);
               // if character is found, remove it
               if (delete(&startPtr, *item)) { // remove item
                  printf("%s deleted.\n", &item);
                  printList(startPtr);
               } 
               else {
                  printf("%s not found.\n\n", &item);
               } 
            } 
            else {
               puts("List is empty.\n");
            } 
            break;

         default:
            puts("Invalid choice.\n");
            instructions();
            break;
      } // end switch
      printf("%s", "? ");
      scanf("%u", &choice);
   } 
   puts("End of run.");
} 
// display program instructions to user
void instructions(void)
{ 
   puts("Enter your choice:\n"
      "   1 to insert an element into the list.\n"
      "   2 to delete an element from the list.\n"
      "   3 to end.");
}

// insert a new value into the list in sorted order
void insert(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char *value)
{ 
   ListNodePtr newPtr = malloc(sizeof(ListNode)); // create node

   if (newPtr != NULL) { // is space available
      newPtr->data= malloc(strlen(value)+1);
      strcpy(newPtr->data, value);
      newPtr->nextPtr = NULL; // node does not link to another node
      ListNodePtr previousPtr = NULL;
      ListNodePtr currentPtr = *sPtr;
      // loop to find the correct location in the list       
      while (currentPtr != NULL && value > currentPtr->data) {
         previousPtr = currentPtr; // walk to ...               
         currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr; // ... next node 
      }                                          
      // insert new node at beginning of list
      if (previousPtr == NULL) { 
         newPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr;
         *sPtr = newPtr;
      } 
      else { // insert new node between previousPtr and currentPtr
         previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
         newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr;
      } 
   } 
   else {
      printf("%s not inserted. No memory available.\n", value);
   } 
} 

// delete a list element
char delete(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char value)
{ 
   // delete first node if a match is found
   if (&value == (*sPtr)->data) { 
      ListNodePtr tempPtr = *sPtr; // hold onto node being removed
      *sPtr = (*sPtr)->nextPtr; // de-thread the node
      free(tempPtr); // free the de-threaded node
      return value;
   } 
   else { 
      ListNodePtr previousPtr = *sPtr;
      ListNodePtr currentPtr = (*sPtr)->nextPtr;
      // loop to find the correct location in the list
      while (currentPtr != NULL && currentPtr->data != value) { 
         previousPtr = currentPtr; // walk to ...  
         currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr; // ... next node  
      } 
      // delete node at currentPtr
      if (currentPtr != NULL) { 
         ListNodePtr tempPtr = currentPtr;
         previousPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;
         free(tempPtr);
         return value;
      } 
   } 
   return '\0';
} 

// return 1 if the list is empty, 0 otherwise
int isEmpty(ListNodePtr sPtr)
{ 
   return sPtr == NULL;
} 


// print the list
void printList(ListNodePtr currentPtr)
{ 
   // if list is empty
   if (isEmpty(currentPtr)) {
      puts("List is empty.\n");
   } 
   else { 
      puts("The list is:");
      // while not the end of the list
      while (currentPtr != NULL) { 
         printf("%s --> ", currentPtr->data);
         currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr;   
      } 
      puts("NULL\n");
   } 
}
```

Comment: This `scanf("%s", &item)` should be `scanf("%s", item)`, and delete should probably be comparing the value of a string, not the address of a char, since that will always be the same (because `item` is always at the same address).

Comment: Got it, thanks @Tibrogargan

Comment: The function `char delete(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char value)` is expecting a single character value, is this intentional? And then you are comparing its address against the structure's data which is a character pointer. This will always return false. In `while (currentPtr != NULL && currentPtr->data != value)` you are comparing the value against a character pointer that may contain a single character (2 including null byte).

Comment: No, it's not intentional, this list, before i upgraded it, was supposed to save a character, not a string, in each node

Answer (score 1):

You have problem using pointers
if made special typedef for ListNodePtr which is ListNode* so use it. Why do you need ListNodePtr*? 
So in some places you are using pointer to pointers to objects 
which makes your code more difficult for understanding.

> (currentPtr != NULL && currentPtr->data != value)

and also here "value" is a single character and you are trying to compare it with "data" which is actually pointer
you should better use something like strcmp()

so the problem starts higher in the declaration of function 
you need to do no that

> char delete(ListNodePtr* sPtr, char value)
>   but that
>   char delete(ListNodePtr* sPtr, char* value)

and please don't use words which are used as key words in the language.
in this case better use "remove"

Comment: Sorry, i know that my code sucks, but i'm having some troubles with these arguments, also i worked on it for the whole day so i only made sure that it works now (insert function is working), i still did not clean it

Answer (score 1):

The ways you define your list, `insert()` and `remove()` are not consistent. Looking at your function declarations, `insert()` expects a `char *` as its second argument where as `delete()` is declared as `void delete (ListNodePtr*, char)`. Do you intend to store a `char` or a string as the key of your list node?

Also, below is a very bad way of comparing (what?)

```
if (&value == (*sPtr)->data)
```

To compare `char`, simply use `==` or `!=` operators, for string comparison, use `strncpy()`. Below is not correct

```
 // loop to find the correct location in the list       
      while (currentPtr != NULL && value > currentPtr->data) {
```

I think, you overused pointers. You `typedef` an alias for your pointer type, yet you pass your functions a `ListNodePtr *sPtr`, which is a pointer to pointer to struct listNode. And then within your functions you dereference `sPtr` to get a `struct *listNode`. Update your function declarations to accept a `ListNodePtr` as the first argument rather than a `ListNodePtr *` and remove dereferencing from the function definitions.

I would use`struct *` instead of a `typedef`, which sometimes hides the details and makes the code a bit confusing.

Comment: Right now the aim of the list is to save into a node my input word, and it does that at the moment, basically i input the string and it allocates the memory to save the world into a node, what i'm trying to do now is to delete the word/string and free the memory it was using

Comment: then your `delete()` should look for strings. Start by fixing the declaration and use a `char *` as the second argument as opposed to `char`, something like this `void delete (ListNodePtr*, char*)`